How to convert the unit of flux from K*m/s to Jy?
I have a data cube which has 3 axes: x(GLAT), y(GLON), v(VELO). Every pixel has value $T(x,y,v)$ in the unit of K. The velocity is in m/s, reference to 1420405751.77 MHz.
if I measure a cloud with flux density:



T (K)
1
1
4
5
1
4




v (m/s)
0
200
400
600
800
1000



how can I calculate the flux of this cloud in Jy?
This data is produced by the Chinese FAST telescope. Example data cube here: https://hiverse.alkaidos.cn/


I don't quite get what velocity you have there. Is it a line-of-sight velocity, thus a redshift(?) with respect to the indicated frequency?

What does temperature multiply by velocity means? Its kinda problematic.


the velocity is a redshift respect to LSR, for example, v=0 is f=1420MHz, then v=1km/s is z = v/c = δf/f , f = (1-v/c)f
@Polaris5744 , this temperature is brightness temperature I=2ν^2 kT/c, I know you don't know this so stop commenting here.


@Firestar-Reimu, what are you talking about, I don't even know who you are, you must have confuse me with someone else.
